# Mongoose populate won't work after "post" middleware

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have the following schemas:

`parent.ts`

```js
export const ParentSchema = new Schema<IParent>(
  {
    children: {
      type: [
        {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'Child',
        },
      ],
      default: [],
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export default model('Parent', ParentSchema, 'Parent');
```

`child.ts`

```js
import Parent from './parent';

const ChildSchema = new Schema<IChild>(
  {
    parent: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Parent',
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

ChildSchema.post('save', async function () {
  const { _id, parent: parentId } = this;
  console.log('pre findByIdAndUpdate');
  await Parent.findByIdAndUpdate(parentId, { $push: { children: _id } });
  console.log('post findByIdAndUpdate');
});

export default model('Child', ChildSchema, 'Child');
```

The `Parent` schema is actually a wrapper of multiple children, so it only makes sense to have a `Parent` if one `Child` is being created as well. So, I have this function:

`parent-service.ts`

```js
async store() {
  const newParent = await new Parent().save();
  const newChild = await new Child({ parent: newParent._id }).save();
  await newParent.populate('children');
  // console.log(await Parent.findById(newParent._id));
  return newParent;
}
```

I would expect that the returned object would be something like:

```json
{
  "_id": "1234567890abcdef",
  "children": [
    {
       "_id": "fedcba0987654321",
       "parent": "1234567890abcdef"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, this is what is being returned by calling `await store()`:

```json
{
  "_id": "1234567890abcdef",
  "children": []
}
```

The `console.log` on `post` middleware at `child.ts` are printed, and if I remove the `console.log` commented out at `parent-service.ts`, it shows that indeed the middleware worked as intended and the `id` was added to the array of children.

Is this behavior expected, is it a bug?

What I've tried:

1. Using `SchemaTypes.ObjectId` instead of `Schema.Types.ObjectId`;
2. Using `updateOne` instead of `findByIdAndUpdate` on the middleware;

I'm currently using, as a workaround, a spread on `newParent` putting `children: [newChild]`, but I'd like to `populate` actually get the updated version of my document.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is expected behavior, the reason being this:

```
async store() {
  const newParent = await new Parent().save(); <-- S1
  const newChild = await new Child({ parent: newParent._id }).save(); <-- S2
  await newParent.populate('children'); <-- S3
  // console.log(await Parent.findById(newParent._id));
  return newParent;
}
```

When `S1` executes, `newParent` points to the object, whose value is this

```
{
  "_id": "1234567890abcdef",
  "children": []
}
```

After this, the child is created and the `save` middleware updates the parent using `findByIdAndUpdate` or `updateOne`. But the thing to note here is, that the updated parent document returned by these functions is not assigned to any variables, let alone `newParent`, also it's not trivial to assign it to `newParent` as well. That's why when you cal `populate` method in `S3`, nothing gets populated, because the value referred to by `newParent`, still has `children` as an empty array.

Now to fix this, you can try this:

1. You can basically call `findByIdAndUpdate`, within the `store` method itself, and store the updated parent object in the `newParent` variable.
2. You can also try overriding the `children` array of `newParent`, in the `store` method by storing the newly created child `_id` in it and then call populate (not recommended).
3. Simply call `findById` for the parent once the child is saved (best option).

Comment: I see your point and it makes sense. Thanks!